# npm install -g @vue/cli get error VUE CLI INSTALL ERROR npm star and vue serve

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-start

> npm start
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall open
> npm ERR! path /home/daniel/package.json
> npm ERR! errno -2
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/daniel/package.json'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/daniel/.npm/_logs/2022-11-11T00_09_58_091Z-debug-0.log

> npm install -g @vue/cli
> npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.11.0: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md

> changed 847 packages, and audited 848 packages in 40s

> 64 packages are looking for funding
> run `npm fund` for details

> 4 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 2 high)

> To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
> npm audit fix --force

> Run `npm audit` for details.

Trying to install vue/cli and trying to run vue will do, but the errors described

Comment: What version of node do you have? Installing the CLI for Vue2?

Comment: nodejs --version = v12.22.9
vue --version = @vue/cli 5.0.8

Comment: v12 is long dead. Please use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and install either v16 or v18.

Comment: vue serve
Running npm run serve
npm ERR! Missing script: "serve"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

     
Node.js v18.12.1

Comment: Where are you running serve? Do you have it in your `package.json`, `scripts` section? Looks like it's not the case. Did you installed `node_modules` before proceeding? Are you using Vue2 as expected (double-check in your `package.json`)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.